# Way to monitor website and taking screenshot on error

Tags: http, web, monitoring, screenshot

is anyone know a way to monitor a website (check for specific content, response time, response status code), and take a screenshot of the "monitor ressource" website (for example on firefox).

On failure, the screenshot is saved, sent by mail, etc...

I know how to take screenshot of a website, I know how to monitor website, but I don't know how to do it at the same time.

Is anyone already try to do the same thing ??

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need:
http://seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Well, I know selenium (but I've never test it....) Are you sure there is a possibility to take screenshot ? I will take a look this afternoon on Selenium. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure. It's used in the company I work at, though not by me.